# ps2pdf not able to include eps files since El Capitan MacOs upgrade "Error: /undefined in startTexFig"

Tags: eps, mac, ps2pdf

I upgraded to El Capitan and now ps2pdf crashes on tex files that used to work fine. The problems occur for tex files that include EPS files.

I'll give the latex source and the error messages first, then the example EPS file at the bottom.

(1) latex source for a file called problemWithPS2PDF.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{psfig.tex}
Some text 

\mbox{\psfig{figure=tinye.eps}}

more text 
\end{document}
```

(2) here is some shell output for latex, dvips, and ps2pdf (my normal 
way of making pdf).

```
484:/Users/djcm1/confid> which ps2pdf
/opt/local/bin/ps2pdf


481:/Users/djcm1/confid> latex problemWithPS2PDF.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./problemWithPS2PDF.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./problemWithPS2PDF.aux) (/Users/djcm1/tex/inputs/psfig.tex
psfig/tex 1.9
)
psfig: searching tinye.eps for bounding box
psfig: including tinye.eps 
[1] (./problemWithPS2PDF.aux) )
Output written on problemWithPS2PDF.dvi (1 page, 384 bytes).
Transcript written on problemWithPS2PDF.log.
482:/Users/djcm1/confid> make problemWithPS2PDF.ps
dvips -R0 problemWithPS2PDF.dvi   -G0  -z -Pcmz -t a4  -o problemWithPS2PDF.ps
dvips: warning: no config file for `cmz'
This is dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2016.02.29:1201' -> problemWithPS2PDF.ps



. 

[1] 
483:/Users/djcm1/confid> ps2pdf problemWithPS2PDF.{ps,pdf}
Error: /undefined in startTexFig
Operand stack:
   4473159   4473159   0   0   4473159   4473159
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1836   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1191/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:101/300(L)--   --dict:101/300(L)--   --dict:23/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 33247
GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

(3) Here is the example EPS file, called tinye.eps

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Title: tiny.fig
%%Creator: fig2dev Version 3.2 Patchlevel 5d
%%CreationDate: Mon Feb 29 11:52:04 2016
%%For: djcm1@mull.local (David J C MacKay)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 68 68
%Magnification: 1.0000
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/$F2psDict 200 dict def
$F2psDict begin
$F2psDict /mtrx matrix put
/col-1 {0 setgray} bind def
/col0 {0.000 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col1 {0.000 0.000 1.000 srgb} bind def

end

/cp {closepath} bind def
/ef {eofill} bind def
/gr {grestore} bind def
/gs {gsave} bind def
/sa {save} bind def
/rs {restore} bind def
/l {lineto} bind def
/m {moveto} bind def
/rm {rmoveto} bind def
/n {newpath} bind def
/s {stroke} bind def
/sh {show} bind def
/slc {setlinecap} bind def
/slj {setlinejoin} bind def
/slw {setlinewidth} bind def
/srgb {setrgbcolor} bind def
/rot {rotate} bind def
/sc {scale} bind def
/sd {setdash} bind def
/ff {findfont} bind def
/sf {setfont} bind def
/scf {scalefont} bind def
/sw {stringwidth} bind def
/tr {translate} bind def
/tnt {dup dup currentrgbcolor
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add srgb}
  bind def
/shd {dup dup currentrgbcolor 4 -2 roll mul 4 -2 roll mul
  4 -2 roll mul srgb} bind def
 /DrawEllipse {
    /endangle exch def
    /startangle exch def
    /yrad exch def
    /xrad exch def
    /y exch def
    /x exch def
    /savematrix mtrx currentmatrix def
    x y tr xrad yrad sc 0 0 1 startangle endangle arc
    closepath
    savematrix setmatrix
    } def

/$F2psBegin {$F2psDict begin /$F2psEnteredState save def} def
/$F2psEnd {$F2psEnteredState restore end} def

/pageheader {
save
newpath 0 68 moveto 0 0 lineto 68 0 lineto 68 68 lineto closepath clip newpath
-143.8 200.4 translate
1 -1 scale
$F2psBegin
10 setmiterlimit
0 slj 0 slc
 0.06000 0.06000 sc
} bind def
/pagefooter {
$F2psEnd
restore
} bind def
%%EndProlog
pageheader
%
% Fig objects follow
% here starts figure with depth 50
% Ellipse
7.500 slw
n 2962 2775 558 558 0 360 DrawEllipse gs col0 s gr

% here ends figure;
pagefooter
showpage
%%Trailer
%EOF
```

---

PS - when I put this tinye.eps file through ps2pdf, it emerges fine as a .pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me when doing latex and dvipdf.
I changed the line

```
\usepackage{psfig}
```

to

```
\usepackage{epsfig,psfig}
```

and now it works again.

Comment: Ghostscript is at version 9.16. Also, if you installed the full MacTeX-2015 it installed 9.18 in /usr/local/bin so your PATH is finding the older version.