# eps pictures don't work in my new LaTeX

Tags: eps, dvi, pdfmark

I have been writing this book for 10 years, no problem with LaTeX-ing. Last week I had to update my MacOS from 10.9 to 10.14. As a result, I had to reinstall my TeXShop, as well. Now I'm getting this error message, and no readable dvi, no pdf. The pictures are in .eps, the first one is on page 26.

```
... everything looks good... [231<./Grigprofile.eps>] 
[232] [233] [234] [235] [236] [237] [238] [239] [240] [241] [242] [243] [244] 
[245] [246] [247] [248] [249] [250] [251] [252] [253] [254] [255] 
### ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5  /tmp/altpdflatex.5519-1606761228/PGG.ps /tmp/altpdflatex.5519-1606761228/PGG.pdf
Error: /undefined in startTexFig
Operand stack:
   10585598   7104430   0   0   21444853   14340423
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:727/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:106/200(L)--   --dict:219/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1272562
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 26 points beyond the last page 25.
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.5519-1606761228/PGG.pdf ()
```

Comment: sorry you are not giving enough information. Try to make a small complete example that demonstrates the error that you can post so that other can test your issue.

Comment: Probably testing the issue won't work, because I expect that somehow my TeX setup is flawed, just I have no idea where. But I will post a small complete example, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Possibly related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296536/ps2pdf-not-able-to-include-eps-files-since-el-capitan-macos-upgrade-error-und

Comment: What TeX Distribution are you using? How are you typesetting the document? You only show the ps2pdf part of the Console output.